# In SQLite (C#) when I UNION two tables I lose column type information

Tags: c#, sqlite

In the code below when I do a query from a single table the type information is perfect... However, when I do a query from a union of two identically defined tables... the type information is lost (to a degree) as follows:

```
Select * from Test1
Name (System.String)
Date (System.DateTime)
Value (System.Int32)

Select * from Test1 UNION Select * from Test2
Name (System.String)
Date (System.String)  <== DateTime converted to String
Value (System.Int64)  <== Int32 converted to Int64
```

Is there a way that I can preserve the type information when I use a UNION?

Code:

```
        sql = "Create Table Test1 " +
            "([Name] string, [Date] date, [Value] int)";
        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
        { command.ExecuteNonQuery(); }

        sql = "Create Table Test2 " +
            "([Name] string, [Date] date, [Value] int)";
        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
        { command.ExecuteNonQuery(); }

        sql = "Insert into Test1 (Name, Date, Value) values (@Name, @Date, @Value)";
        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Name", "John Doe"));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Date", DateTime.Parse("11/30/1958")));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Value", 1));
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        sql = "Insert into Test2 (Name, Date, Value) values (@Name, @Date, @Value)";
        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Name", "Brian Rice"));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Date", DateTime.Parse("12/1/1970")));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Value", 2));
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        sql = "Select * from Test1";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            // create data adapter
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sql);
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName + " (" + column.DataType + ")");

        sql = "Select * from Test1 UNION Select * from Test2";
        dt = new DataTable();
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            // create data adapter
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sql);
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName + " (" + column.DataType + ")");
```

Comment: If you change from `SELECT *` to `SELECT Name, Date, Value`, does that help?

Comment: As far as I know type of a column in SQLite database is inferred from the data in the column. That means data in the second table is preventing SQLite to infer a common type.

Comment: @idursun, if you look at the code I provided the data I insert is of the correct type.

Comment: @DavidG, it doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it fixed here.

Create a view instead

```
  CREATE VIEW "vwTest" AS Select * from Test1 UNION Select * from Test2
```

Then you should select from the view

```
  Select * from vwTest
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) there are no *real*, or maybe I should say, no *conventional* data types in  SQLite 3. It states expressedly that neither Date, Datetime nor Bool exist.

Instead there are `Storage Classes`:

- NULL. The value is a NULL value.
- INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
- REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.
- TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
- BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

And there is concept of *type affinity*
 which organizes conversion between the various classes and sub-classes as needed. (!?)

Which may well be the reason why either SQLite internally or the .NET interface makes the conversions you notice, in the course of processing a `UNION` statement. 
Here is another interesting quote from the docs:

*SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values..*

Looks like, when parsing the `UNION's SELECT` statements, each column is converted to its most general sub-class it might find later on: for all INTs it will be INT64, which is obvious; and for DATEs is it STRING, which is less obvious but still plausible..

Since your tables are identical and your values pretty much as well it seems to be an provision one has to live with, I'm afraid, unless a different interface would act differently..

Comment: I understand the things you're saying (and have experienced them in the past, particularly with dates) which is why I was so pleasantly surprised when C# SQLite was converting them so nicely for me... until I did a UNION! %(